# Wrap content when content size overflows the parent container

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap content when content size overflows the parent div.

```css
td{
  background: pink;
  width:20px;
}

td div{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
              mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
              
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is not working. Why ?

Comment: You can apply `display: block;` to `td`, Not the best solution but that will wrap the content inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-all;`

```css
td{
  background: pink;
  width:20px;
}

td div{
word-break: break-all;
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;  /* CSS 2.1 */
white-space: pre-line; /* CSS 3 */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id= "mydiv">
              mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
              
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `word-break: break-all;` property instead of `word-wrap: break-word;`.

```css
td {
  background: pink;
  width: 20px;
}

td div {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```